# How to redirect a port using IPTables in Red Hat Linux (RHEL)?

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'd like to forward port 80 to 8080.
So I tried to edit `/etc/syscongfig/iptables`:

```
-A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

But got:

```
# service iptables restart
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter          [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.4.7: 
          Line 8 seems to have a -t table  option.
```

What's the problem?
How should it be done?

Answer (score 3):

Does file `/etc/syscongfig/iptables` have correct structure for iptables-restore?

Try to add this rule manually to firewall

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

And compare `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` with output of `iptables-save` command

Comment: Related: [Error when doing port forwarding with iptables?](http://askubuntu.com/q/175757)

Answer (score 1):

This is your [`iptables`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) rule:

```
-A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

But I believe it should be something like this instead:

```
-A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Note the `-m tcp` is added. While `-p tcp` matches the protocol of the rule or of the packet to check, `-m tcp` explicitly tells IPTables to match a TCP packet. It seems confusing, but from all I know, `-p tcp` needs to be paired with `-m tcp` when port specific rules are invoked.

If someone else can expand the rationale/logic behind this requirement please chime in about it in the comments.

Comment: The `-m tcp` is added automatically because `-p tcp` is specified. You can see this when you execute `iptables-save`. While `iptables` can be quite complex, it does its best to aid the user.